# Long Press Button issue on moving mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

I use a long press button, which works very well, on MouseDown and if I don't move the mouse, at the end of my delay, I have my action.
If I move the mouse (still pressing down and still on the button) it resets my button's delay, and I don't understand why.
if anyone has an idea, it would help me a lot.
Thx

Here's my code :

```
private bool _PointerDown;
public float DelaiReponse;
private float _PointerDownTimer;
private bool _IsValidate = false;
private float _Delai;

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _PointerDown = true;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _PointerDown = false;
    _PointerDownTimer = 0;
}

void Start()
{
   _Delai = DelaiReponse;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (_PointerDown) // Timer Button Validation Hold
    {
        _PointerDownTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (_PointerDownTimer >= _Delai)
        {
            _IsValidate = true;
        }
    }
}enter code here
```

Comment: are you sure when you move mouse, OnPointerUp is not called (have you check with Debug.Log or break?)

Comment: have you same effect with Input.GetMouseDown(0) and Input.GetMouseUp(0)?

Comment: No, using Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) and Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0), fix the problem, Thanks

Comment: i just post the answer to finalize the problem, dont forget to validate and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Input.GetMouseDown(0) and  Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) could fix the problem:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseDown(0))
    {
        _PointerDown = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseUp(0))
    {
        _PointerDown = false;
        _PointerDownTimer = 0;
    }

    if (_PointerDown) // Timer Button Validation Hold
    {
       :
       :
    }
    :
    :
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found
OnMouseDown even worked outside my button, and I preferred the OnPointerDown method.
I added IDragHandler to my class, and create a bool _PointerDrag

```
private bool _PointerDown;
private bool _PointerDrag;
public float DelaiReponse;
private float _PointerDownTimer;
private bool _IsValidate = false;
private float _Delai;

public class LongClickButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _PointerDown = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _PointerDown = false;
        _PointerDownTimer = 0;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _PointerDrag = true;
    }

    void Start()
    {
       _Delai = DelaiReponse;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_PointerDown || _PointerDrag) // Timer Button Validation Hold
        {
            _PointerDownTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_PointerDownTimer >= _Delai)
            {
                _IsValidate = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it works.

Thanks for your time, Frenchy